# the differences of bazel cc_library

Tags: bazel

In WORKSPACE opencv4 is introduced, what are the differences between 2 ways of bazel cc_library for a Target depend on opencv4?

```
new_local_repository(
name = "linux_opencv",
build_file = "@//third_party:opencv_linux.BUILD",
path = "/usr/local",
)
```

```
cc_library(
name = "opencv4_a",
hdrs = glob([
"include/opencv4/opencv2/\*\*/*.h*",
]),

includes = ["include/opencv4/",],

linkopts =[
    "-L/usr/local/lib",
    "-l:libopencv_core.so",
    "-l:libopencv_calib3d.so",
    "-l:libopencv_features2d.so",
    "-l:libopencv_highgui.so",
    "-l:libopencv_imgcodecs.so",
    "-l:libopencv_imgproc.so",
    "-l:libopencv_video.so",
    "-l:libopencv_videoio.so",
],

)
```

and another version of cc_library:

```
cc_library(
name = "opencv4_b",
srcs = glob(
    [
    "lib/libopencv_core.so",
    "lib/libopencv_highgui.so",
    "lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so",
    "lib/libopencv_imgproc.so",
    "lib/libopencv_video.so",
    "lib/libopencv_videoio.so",
    ]),
hdrs = glob(["include/opencv4/opencv2/**/*.h*"]),
includes = ["include/opencv4/",],
linkstatic = 1,
visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

I just want know the differences of 2 ways to define cc_library above， they used linkopts and srcs respectively.

Added:

for a cc_binary will depend on opencv4 above, what are the differences?
It seems the using way is the same:

```
cc_binary(   
 name = "executable",   
 src = ["a.cpp","c.cpp","c.h"],   
 deps = [:opencv4_a],    // or deps = [:opencv4_b]   
)
```

Comment: srcs specifies source files to be used as inputs to a rule, while linkopts specifies options to be passed to the linker when linking the output of a rule.

Comment: what is defference  bewteen  cc_binary  depend on  opencv4_a and   opencv4_b?  if  cc_binary  depend on opencv4_a, it must explicitly add linkopts ?